# Using FFMPEG to create video from images in sub folders

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, linux

I know I can create a video from files in a folder like so:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i %*.png out.avi
```

But if the folder I am in have sub-folders can i use some sort of switch to read those image files in those sub-folders?  At the moment I am having to copy these image files into 1 folder, create the video and then delete those copied image files. Which is time consuming .

Is there a way please?

Thanks

Comment: The image reader won't recurse folders. Instead of copying the images, create symlinks in one folder. Much faster. Or use the concat demuxer. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer

Comment: many thanks  only had the time now to look at this:)

Answer (score 1):

While you can go with the links approach, suggested by [Gyan](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/1871/gyan) in the comments. You could also generate a list of files that you want to use for encoding, and then use `-f concat`. I have tried it with the following:

```
find . -name '*.jpeg' -exec echo "file '"{}"'" >> list.text \;
ffmpeg  -f concat -r 25 -safe 0 -i list.text -c:v libtheora -q:v 8 out.ogv
```

Let's take it apart.

First we generate the list of all the files matching '*.jpeg' name starting with the current directory `.`, we do not want to output that list as is, because `ffmpeg` for whatever reason cannot default to lines being files, and expects us to say it each and every line. So rather than `my_image_001.jpeg` we want `file 'my_image_001.jpeg'`. So we do a trick with the `-exec` of `find` piping the `echo` command into a file. `list.text` in this example.

Now we get to `ffmpeg`. You tell it that you wish to concatenate all of the files, by providing `-f concat` as the format of the file it is about to read. Note that you will need to specify the frame rate, since images do not have this at all. The `-safe 0` is needed so that `ffmpeg` does not crash and burn with `Unsafe file name` error message. I believe that is because we are using paths relative to the current directory. It makes little sense, but you just need to do this. After this, the line is the same as if you were just re-encoding another video.

Comment: Thanks. Good to see an alternative. But I did follow the link from Gyan May and it offers a cleaner solution for my business case.